# Python Flask MQTT

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I have been searching the internet and testing on my Raspberry Pi Flask server on how to us MQTT with Flask.

I have a flask server that an Arduino MKR1000 publishes that status of my garage doors (open or closed). I had tried UDP but I kept losing data or "connection".

When running a simple python script on the Pi with mosquito, I can publish and subscribe no problem. Data goes between the Pi and Arduino perfectly. The problem I am running into is how to implement MQTT/mosquitto into the flask app.py. I read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436412/python-flask-and-mqtt-listening) and this sound exactly like what I want to do.
Can someone explain to me how to do this? Maybe @ g19fanatic?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I found my problem. I was using the built in flask server and kept getting a "broken pipe" error because of it. MQTT works fine. Just need to upgrade my server to Apache or django.